# How do I get dead keys working?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, ibus

I´d like to start by saying that i´ve searched other questions about this and none of the answers are working for me.

I´m using the standard Ubuntu 18.4 (gnome I think?) loading off a memory stick to test this out before I make the plunge properly. No matter what I do I can´t get the built in keyboard layouts through the settings menu to work properly. Ive found and selected US international with deadkeys but the deadkeys don´t work.

Running ibus-steup and unticking some options there as some answers to other questions suggest does nothing.

Ive been able to get into a mode that works like the Windows US International keyboard with working deadkeys by following a different answer and typing setxkbmap -layout us -variant intl into the terminal, but I cant figure out how to get back to the regular UK layout from there, let alone figure out how to set it up so that I can quickly switch between them.

Can someone help me out here please?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out in the end, just needed to step back and think about it.

For anyone else with the same problem, my solution was to go into Settings > Keyboard and create two shortcuts, one for "setxkbmap -layout us -variant intl" and one for "sekxkbmap -layout gb", and I can now use these to change my keyboard back and forth.

Still mildly irked that this is a built in option that just doesn't work, but there you go.